# Session Storage not working

Tags: javascript, html, session

I am getting session values and trying to store it in html using Id. When I alert the value in javascript function, it shows the value in session but it does not set it in HTML.

```js
function result() {
  var quantScore = sessionStorage.getItem('quantData');
  var quantAns = sessionStorage.getItem('mathQuestion');
  var readingCorrectAns = sessionStorage.getItem('readcorrect');
  var readingAns = sessionStorage.getItem('readans');

  var audvidScore = sessionStorage.getItem('audiovideoData');
  var audvidAns = sessionStorage.getItem('audiovideoQuestion');

  document.getElementById("quantque").innerHTML = quantAns;
  document.getElementById("quantscore").innerHTML = quantScore;

  document.getElementById("readque").innerHTML = readingAns;
  document.getElementById("readans").innerHTML = readingCorrectAns;

  document.getElementById("audvidque").innerHTML = audvidAns;
  document.getElementById("audvidscore").innerHTML = audvidScore
}
```

```html
<body onload="result()">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="top">Score Card</div>
    <section class="section1">
      <div class="border">
        <details>
          <summary>Quantitative Section</summary>
          <p><b>Number of Questions Answered: <span id = "quantque"> </span><br>
        Number of Correct Answered: <span id = "quantans"> </span><br>
        Score: <span id = "qunatscore"> </span><br></b></p>
        </details>
        <details>
          <summary>Reading Section</summary>
          <p><b>Number of Questions Answered: <span id = "readque"> </span><br>
        Number of Correct Answered: <span id = "readans"> </span><br>
        Score: <span id = "readscore"> </span><br></b></p>
        </details>
        <details>
          <summary>Audio/Video Section</summary>
          <p><b>Number of Questions Answered: <span id = "audvidque"> </span><br>
        Number of Correct Answered: <span id = "audvidans"> </span><br>
        Score: <span id = "audvidscore"> </span></b></p>
        </details> <br>
      </div>
      <h2 style="text-align : center;"> Thank You !</h2>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Finish" />
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: and where is saved on sessionStorage?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón I am getting values in var variables, its just that, it doesn't work when I try to use innerHTML

Comment: my ask is where is  sessionStorage.putItem

Comment: Check again, if elements you are setting `innerHTML`  for, are available when your `result` function is executing.